# any maven plugin like versions:set update dependency version

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

any maven plugin like versions:set update dependency version to a specific value?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.cps</groupId>
    <artifactId>cps</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
<dependency>
```

ref:http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-132